# Changing primary key in Django caused constraint does not exist error

Tags: django, database-migration

I have Django project with `DigestIssue` model among others and there were Django auto created primary key field `id` and my field `number`. I wanted to get rid of duplication and set `number` as PK because `number` is unique and with same values as `id`. But I have foreign keys referencing this model.

I doubt that they will migrate automatically after such operation. I tried, hoping for such automigration and got `constraint "idx_16528_sqlite_autoindex_gatherer_digestissue_1" of relation "gatherer_digestissue" does not exist` error ("sqlite" in constraint name is historical thing, I switched to PostgreSQL a time go). I tried more complicated way, following https://blog.hexack.fr/en/change-the-primary-key-of-a-django-model.html but got same error on PK switching step.

So the question is - how to replace in Django old primary key with new one with same values and referenced by other models?

Comment: "_`number` is unique and with same values as `id`_", just remove the number field then, why go through the trouble of renaming / changing your primary key.

Comment: It could be a great idea, but I forgot to mention - `id` starts from 1 and it is autofield, but I need to add record with `number = 0` to this model and I could not set `id` to be 0.